# which version of slf4j-log4j12 to use with hibernate 3.6.0.Final (having internal dependency of slf4j-api 1.5.8)

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, struts2

I'm using hibernate-core 3.6.0.Final & hibernate-annotations 3.5.6-Final.

Hibernate has dependency of slf4j-api 1.5.8 so it's gets added to my maven project dependencies automatically.

But when I try running the project I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

Googling says that this is due to difference in versions of slf4j and slf4j-log4j12 and arises mainly using hibernate 3.3

I added :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Alternatively, both and one-by-one but none of the options solve the problem. I'm still getting the `IllegalAccessError`. 
It'll be great if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following dependencies of log4j and slf4j in my pom.xml. It is working fine for me, hope this helps you also

```
    <properties>
      <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
      <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: It seemed to work, although I solved my problem by using 
           `<dependency>

            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>

            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>

        </dependency>`
instead of 
        `<dependency>

            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>

        </dependency>`

and included the same version of slf4j-log4j12 as the internal dependency of hibernate which came out to be 1.6.1